# MySQL not storing foreign characters correctly

Tags: .net, mysql, utf-8, cjk

Using SQLite, this works fine. However, when I switch to MySQL, instead of `ｸｲﾝ` i get `???`. The column is TEXT or sometimes VARCHAR(255) (I believe its VARCHAR(255) in this case).

How do I get MySQL to properly save these characters?

Comment: Is SQLITE storing it as UTF-8?  What's the default character set of your MySQL server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Table/column character sets need to be set to a version that supports multibyte like UTF8.

You may be able to tell the current table character set by doing a

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_Name;
```

It may not show you anything in which case it's using the default defined in you my.cnf

To change a character set on a table run:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I don't recommend this if you have a lot of data or can't remove the data and start fresh. The transition needs to remove the bad data first.

I read through this post and it seems in depth and from what I can remember of my own battles with this very accurate. http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html

Also, to create new tables as UTF-8 append *CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci* to the end of your **CREATE TABLE** statements

Comment: converting the character set doesn't convert the data.  Use the command with care, only as part of an overall migration strategy.

Comment: As pointed out directly below the command. It was to convert the table for future storage not to convert the data currently in the table.

Comment: Its a prototype so i can start with fresh data. AFAIK .NET uses 16bit chars (i dont know if its UTF encoded/supports>16bits character). Would setting UTF-8 force me to pass the data as utf8? I tried writing `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` after  TEXT and varchar(255) yet it still gives me ?? instead.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_Name; outputs  ` name varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,`

Comment: Like volody mentioned below ensure you're connecting with charset=UTF8 in your connection string.

I created a MYSQL table using utf8 with varchar & text utf8 columns. Inserted `ｸｲﾝ` and everything showed up fine. Are you verifying the data at the server level or when the data comes back? Try manually inserting the data into one of the columns and see if it sticks.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you have specified "charset=utf8" in your connection string. For example

```
connectionString="Server=myServerHost;charset=UTF8;Database=myDatabase;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
```

As noted in [Character Sets and Collations in General](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-general.html) 
MySQL can do:

- Store strings using a variety of character sets
- Compare strings using a variety of collations
- Mix strings with different character sets or collations in the same server, the same database, or even the same table
- Allow specification of character set and collation at any level